# SMTP server response: 550 Invalid recipient to a simple email feature

Tags: php, email, smtp

i am creating a website using php that sends confirmation messages through emails..

to edit my php.ini, i followed this walkthrough:

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mail.php

i downloaded a free smtp server to test the connections, i used port 25, and the DNS server as localhost. I use this server to test if the email i send is being connected

i used this simple code to test the mail() function:

```
<?php
$to = 'myownemail@yahoo.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$from = 'email@domain.com';
$message = 'hello';

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, "From: $from"))
  echo "Mail sent";
else
  echo "Mail send failure - message not sent"; ?>
```

when running, the smtp server indicates that the current active connection is the "myownemail@yahoo.com".

but the website shows this error message:

SMTP server response: 550 Invalid recipient

what should i do? i am very new to development and used smtp for the first time so i have no idea what is happening

PS. I got the smtp server here> softstack.com/freesmtp.html

Comment: tell us something about the smtp server

Comment: Is myownemail@yahoo.com an actual email address?

Comment: Yes, myownemail@yahoo.com is an actual email address.

Comment: this is the website where i downloaded the smtp servver: http://www.softstack.com/freesmtp.html

Comment: Are you using the SMTP server to send the emails or as a test server to receive the emails?

Comment: im using it to send emails to my own email

Comment: can soomeone please help me with this problem.. im desperate..:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For testing you could try [this](http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/) tool, called Test Mail Server Tool, instead. It has the benefit of not sending actual emails thus spamming your account, but saving/opening the email on your desktop, the same email which would have been sent. You can examine the headers this way and debug more easily and much faster. Note that it's useless in production, and testing remotely. It was not meant for that.

Comment: i have one question, what email should i use for the to variable?

Comment: no e-mail is sent so you can use anything, the point is that you should see in the opened email the same recipient as the one in the sending script

Comment: okay, i tested it, and it receives the email in the designated folder. it means im sending emails correctly, am i right?

Comment: That's true, but please pay attention to the "from", "to" and "cc" fields, no artifacts or anything beside email addresses should be present there. Also in the mail form try using email-injection, a really common contact form hack. Google it for more information.

Comment: i still dont know why i dont receive the messages in my email. i needed it to work real bad

Comment: with this testing tool I gave you, you'll never receive, like I said, it's for testing not for sending email. If you receive it with that means your script works, and mails will be sent in a correctly configured normal smtp server, that's all, you should use a real smtp server like you did before for actually sending an email, and in which case I can't help you, I wasn't giving a solution but an alternative

Comment: so it means there is something wrong with my smtp server configurations, since even though i am using a real smtp server, i still dont receive the emails i am sending

Answer (score 0):

Remove `$from` in request header from inside quotes and try using a valid email address.

```
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, "From: " . $from))
```

Comment: "From: " . $from is the same as "From: $from"